# How to adda KeyboardEvnt in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to add KeyboardEvntArgs to this code.

how to add

```
e.SupressKeypress = True
```

to this

===================

This is KeyboardHook function

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class KeyboardHook

    <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Private Overloads Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal HookProc As KBDLLHookProc, ByVal hInstance As IntPtr, ByVal wParam As Integer) As Integer
    End Function
    <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Private Overloads Shared Function CallNextHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function
    <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Private Overloads Shared Function UnhookWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
        Public vkCode As UInt32
        Public scanCode As UInt32
        Public flags As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags
        Public time As UInt32
        Public dwExtraInfo As UIntPtr
    End Structure

    <Flags()> _
    Private Enum KBDLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags As UInt32
        LLKHF_EXTENDED = &H1
        LLKHF_INJECTED = &H10
        LLKHF_ALTDOWN = &H20
        LLKHF_UP = &H80
    End Enum

    Public Shared Event KeyDown(ByVal Key As Keys)
    Public Shared Event KeyUp(ByVal Key As Keys)

    Private Const WH_KEYBOARD_LL As Integer = 13
    Private Const HC_ACTION As Integer = 0
    Private Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100
    Private Const WM_KEYUP = &H101
    Private Const WM_SYSKEYDOWN = &H104
    Private Const WM_SYSKEYUP = &H105

    Private Delegate Function KBDLLHookProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer

    Private KBDLLHookProcDelegate As KBDLLHookProc = New KBDLLHookProc(AddressOf KeyboardProc)
    Private HHookID As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

    Private Function KeyboardProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
        If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then
            Dim struct As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
            Select Case wParam
                Case WM_KEYDOWN, WM_SYSKEYDOWN
                    RaiseEvent KeyDown(CType(CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, struct.GetType()), KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT).vkCode, Keys))
                Case WM_KEYUP, WM_SYSKEYUP
                    RaiseEvent KeyUp(CType(CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, struct.GetType()), KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT).vkCode, Keys))
            End Select
        End If
        Return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam)
    End Function

    Public Sub New()
        HHookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KBDLLHookProcDelegate, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetModules()(0)).ToInt32, 0)
        If HHookID = IntPtr.Zero Then
            Throw New Exception("Could not set keyboard hook")
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        If Not HHookID = IntPtr.Zero Then
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(HHookID)
        End If
        MyBase.Finalize()
    End Sub

End Class
```

======

How to add `e.supresskeypress = true` into the following code.

```
Private Sub kbHook_KeyDown(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles kbHook.KeyDown

e.supresskeypress = true          '''''doesn't work

End Sub
```

Comment: What is kbHook ? Probably a textbox.

Comment: @MukulVarshney : `kbHook` is an instance of the `KeyboardHook` class.

Comment: @Nilantha : The short answer is: you can't. The `SuppressKeyPress` property is designed to _not_ pass key press messages to the underlying control. It will only work in your application in Windows Forms. -- If you want to block a key you would have to intercept the key's window message, which can be a rather difficult task to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to hook the key board i.e. trapping the keys. `SuppressKeyPress` belongs to `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs`. Your code uses `CallNextHookEx` it means you are passing the keyboard events to next hook. Hence you just want to suppress the events for your application. Pardon me if I understood wrong.

1. In order to this you need to create an instance of `KeyEventArgs` in `KeyboardProc` function and pass it as an argument when you raise the event.
2. Alternately, you can filter and raise events only for valid keys or combinations within `KeyboardProc`.
3. Alternately you can refer the [article](http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/11087_2193301_3/Managing-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hooks-in-VB-NET.htm)

Comment: In order to this you need to create an instance of KeyEventArgs in KeyboardProc function and pass it as an argument when you raise the event.
====================

how to create an instance of KeyEventArgs in KeyboardProc function and pass it to as an argument when the event is raised. ???

Comment: Exactly... its difficult as we need to look into definition of  KeyEventArgs and create our own. Hence I gave the alternate options to achieve the results.